# Has integration been done for Textify Mobile?

Tags: extension, sms

Has anyone seen this new SMS service called Textify Mobile that's geared directly to non-profits and churches. It even has mobile giving with it. Wondering if anyone had done an integration/extension for it?

Answer (score 6):

My name is Mitch Cannon, and I'm the VP of Technology for Textify Mobile. We currently only offer a private API for specific integrations and partnerships. With that said, we are actively developing a RESTful, JSON-based API for our general user base. I would love to talk with anyone interested in an integration about their needs and what we can currently accommodate.

http://www.textifymobile.com/contact-us

Answer (score 2):

I dont think so, but it does seem like Civi should have the ability to handle/interface with mobile giving platforms, since more of giving is happening via phones

Answer (score 1):

Altough they don't have a giving mechanism integrated perhaps you could check [this](http://www.twilio.org) if you are looking to integrate SMS notifications with CiviCRM. They do have discounts (sometimes up to a full discount) for non-profits. And they have an extension for CiviCRM. Hope this helps :D.

Answer (score 1):

I did some looking, but it seems like Textify Mobile doesn't offer an API for this - so integrations aren't possible.  I just submitted a question about this via their help form and will update this answer if I receive a response.

Answer (score -2):

There is not an extension for Twilio currently, so that won't work.  Only Clickatell.

Comment: I'm using twilio so yes there is an extension

Comment: The twilio extension is at: https://civicrm.org/extensions/twilio-sms-provider

Comment: Interesting, the docs say their is not one.  Maybe I will give that a try since my Clickatell solution is not working for 4.6.2.

Comment: can you give a link to the docs which say there is no integration. If its on the wiki, can you please edit and fix the docs